# Does restriction on spin in orbits exist?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, orbitals

For a valence electron in Antimony (Sb) with the electron configuration:

$Kr(5s)^2(4d)^{10}(5p)^3$

The 3 valence electrons have the quantum numbers $n=5,l=1,m=1$, resulting in the following possibilities for $(n,l,m_l,m_s)$:

$(5,1,−1,−\frac{1}{2});(5,1,−1,\frac{1}{2});(5,1,1,−\frac{1}{2});(5,1,1,\frac{1}{2});(5,1,0,−\frac{1}{2});(5,1,0,\frac{1}{2})(5,1,−1,−\frac{1}{2})$

$(5,0,0,−\frac{1}{2});(5,0,0,\frac{1}{2})$

Then looking at the actual quantum numbers of Sb (from a former exam) it is given as:

$(5,1,−1,-\frac{1}{2});(5,1,1,-\frac{1}{2});(5,1,0,-\frac{1}{2})$

$(5,0,0,−\frac{1}{2});(5,0,0,\frac{1}{2})$

Where did the quantum sets with $l=1$ and $m_s=−\frac{1}{2}$ go? When I look at the valence electrons in Kr the set is **with** $l=1$ and $m_s=−\frac{1}{2}$:

$(4,1,−1,−\frac{1}{2});(4,1,−1,\frac{1}{2});(4,1,1,−\frac{1}{2});(4,1,1,\frac{1}{2});(4,1,0,−\frac{1}{2});(4,1,0,\frac{1}{2})
(4,0,0,−\frac{1}{2});(4,0,0,\frac{1}{2})$

Summing up the question: Why can the valence electrons in Kr have $l=1$ and $m_s=−\frac{1}{2}$ and the ones in Sb not? Perhaps it is a mistake in the exam?

Comment: Look at the electronic configuration: you only have 3 electrons in the p orbitals for Sb, whereas you have 6 for Kr. Thus the valence shell is full for the latter and incomplete for the former.

Comment: There are three electrons in the $5p$ so the possible *total* spin quantum numbers are $3/2,\, 1/2$ with multiplicities $2S+1$ of  $4 $ and $2$ which produce quartet and doublet states. In Kr all the orbitals are filled so total spin (and orbital angular momentum) is zero and multiplicity one , so this is a singlet state. If you need to include orbital angular momentum then you will need to look up term symbols and Russell-Saunders coupling.

Comment: The term symbols for $p^3$ are $^2D_{3/2}; ^2D_{1/2},\,^2P_{3/2}; ^2P_{1/2},\, ^4S_{3/2}$.  The orbital angular momentum has values $L= 2,\,1,\,0$  and has to be combined with the spin terms.  To work all of this  out map out a table of microstates of *l* and *s* and eliminate those not possible by the Pauli principle.

Comment: Why is it that the total spin quantum numbers are positive, could they not be negative, allowing for $(5,1,1,\frac{1}{2}$ or $5,1,1,-\frac{1}{2}$ @porphyrin

Comment: Only electron  and orbital angular momentum matter here. If angular momentum  is $A_1 ,\, A_2 $ these are added according to the (Clebsh-Gordon) type series, which is  similar to  adding integer length vectors, so cannot be negative.  To find the series find the max value $A_1+A_2$ then the minimum $|A_1-A_2| $ (which is the absolute value) then fill in gaps (if any) in unit steps; thus if $A_1=5/2, \,A_2 =1$ then series is $7/2, \, 5/2,\,3/2$